# Paginating data causing unusual behavior?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am displaying "global posts" on one of my tabs. Currently, there are only 11 posts in the database:

[image]

In the app **Some**  of the posts are being duplicated, and I have no idea why these SPECIFIC posts are being duplicated, as it seems to me like it is happening at random.

Here is the code for how I paginate the data.

1. When the component mounts, I query firestore and pull 5 posts using getCollection().

.

```
async componentDidMount() {
   
 this.unsubscribe = Firebase.firestore()
.collection('globalPosts')
.orderBy("date_created", "desc")
.limit(5)
.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);  

}
```

2. I get the posts successfully in getCollection(), and set an index, lastItemIndex, so I know where to query for the next posts

.

```
getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
        const globalPostsArray = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
        const { 
            ..fields
            } = res.data();

            globalPostsArray.push({
                ..fields
            });
        });


        this.setState({
            globalPostsArray,
            isLoading: false, 
            lastItemIndex: globalPostsArray.length - 1
        });
}
```

3. This gets the first 5 items, no problem, ordered by date_created, descending.

If the user scrolls down the flatlist, I have logic in the flatlist to handle fetching more data:

```
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.globalPostsArray}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                onRefresh={this._refresh}
                refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} <---------------------- Threshold
                onEndReached={() => {this.getMore()}} <------------ Get more data
            />
```

4. Finally, once it is time to retrieve more data, I call this.getMore()

Here is the code to get the next 5 posts:

```
getMore = async() => {
    const newPostsArray = [] <-------- new array for the next 5 posts

    Firebase.firestore()
    .collection('globalPosts')
    .orderBy("date_created", "desc")
    .startAfter(this.state.globalPostsArray[this.state.lastItemIndex].date_created) <--- note start after
    .limit(5)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
            const { 
                ... same fields as getCollection()
                } = res.data();

                newPostsArray.push({
                    ... same fields as getCollection()
                });
            });

            
            this.setState({
                globalPostsArray: this.state.globalPostsArray.concat(newPostsArray), <--- add to state array
                lastItemIndex: this.state.globalPostsArray.length-1 <---- increment index
            });

            console.log(this.state.lastItemIndex) <------- I print out last item index
    })
}
```

Some notes:

1. The code works fine in terms of fetching the data
2. The code works fine in terms of pagination, and only fetches 5 posts at a time
3. There is no discernible pattern I am seeing in which posts are being duplicated
4. I am ordering by date_created, descending when querying firestore in both getCollection() and getMore()
5. I console log "last item index" in my getMore(), and of course the index is higher than the number of posts
6. I keep getting the following warning/error, with different keys (post ID's in firestore), which shows me the duplication is happening at random, and not specific to one user. This warning/error doesn't break the application, but is telling me this weird behavior is happening:

   Encountered two children with the same key, `ZJu3FbhzOkXDM5mn6O6T`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Can someone point me in the right direction, why my pagination is having such unusual behavior?

Comment: You're **reading** data from the collection, I can't see how you are **writing** data from the collection. There's no way to duplicate data in random by just reading from the collection. Can you share more of your code, it is better if you have GitHub repository.

Comment: @EdisonPebojot I am appending a new array to an existing array, which is duplicating data. My guess is, when I "get more", this query is fetching data that I have already previously fetched and is appending it to the state array - I am not sure how to fix this issue, if my hypothesis is correct.

Comment: @EdisonPebojot when I query firestore and don't paginate, I have no duplicates. When I query firestore with the above pagination logic, I am getting duplicates. This is how I came to the conclusion that querying again and appending the data to the existing array is the issue

Comment: Did you try: `new Set(array)`. **new Set** can remove duplicates from the array. Please refer [Set - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: @EdisonPebojot are you saying, when I concat the new array to the existing array, I do it like so: new Set(globalPostsArray: this.state.globalPostsArray.concat(newPostsArray))?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot I was able to figure it out, the issue was with my index. Posted answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was with `lastItemIndex`. Saving it in state was causing problems. I solved the problem by removing `lastItemIndex` from state, and making it a local variable in getMore():

```
getMore = async() => {
    const newPostsArray = []

    const lastItemIndex = this.state.globalPostsArray.length - 1 <---- added it here

    await Firebase.firestore()
    .collection('globalPosts')
    .orderBy("date_created", "desc")
    .startAfter(this.state.globalPostsArray[lastItemIndex].date_created)
    .limit(5)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
            const { 
                ..fields
                } = res.data();

                newPostsArray.push({
                    key: res.id,
                    ..fields
                });
            });

            
            this.setState({
                globalPostsArray: this.state.globalPostsArray.concat(newPostsArray)
            });

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only guarantee uniqueness on a document ID, not by the contents of a document's fields.

For example, as a workaround, you could concatenate two IDs into a single string and use it as the document ID. You would then use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to ensure that a document does not already exist with that new composite ID before writing it.

In order to paginate through a list of these unique items you need to use `.startAfter()` and `.limit()`. You can then create a `lastVisible` variable that uses the last document in a batch to start a cursor for the next.

```
var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
```

The example below can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) if you want to read more about it:

```
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible) // <--- HERE 
          .limit(25);
});
```

Comment: I already have unique ID's. Is there any way I can iterate over the array after the new fetch and remove duplicates? I am confused as to why duplicates are appearing in the first place